# Skyrim Special Edition SKSE error

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am trying to run Skyrim Special Edition via SKSE with mods, but when I run it it gives me the error

> "You are using Skyrim version 1.5.80, which is out of date and incompatible with this version of SKSE64. Update to the latest version."

How can I fix this?

I've tried to run the BestofBothWorlds patcher from Nexusmods but it didn't help me. I also tried to find a patch manually but I didn't find anything. If you know where I can find a patch for the game suitable for SKSE64 please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every version of Skyrim has it's own version of SKSE. You can either update your version of Skyrim - as the warning states - or download an older version of SKSE from [their archive](https://skse.silverlock.org/download/archive/), which is linked to on the team's [front page](https://skse.silverlock.org/) (which is the only legal way to get SKSE, IIRC).

The newest version of Skyrim Special Edition version is [1.6.353](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Special_Edition_Patch). Try to update your Skyrim version using the service you're playing it on.

Comment: Do you have an idea which version of SKSE is most suitable for my Skyrim SE version 1.5.80?

Comment: "Version 1.5. 80.0. 8 was released as an update for Steam, PS4 and Xbox One on 13 June 2019." Looking at the archive, the first file released after that date is version **2.00.16** (direct linking is not allowed). The readme file contained in that archive file mentions how it is suitable for your version.

Comment: Thank you very much :)